# how to pull specific info from a string with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I very new to jquery/javascript (*entry level job*) and got a customer that needs to pull only the mail info.

he has a `userData` variable that contains

```
{
  name:"name surname", 
  email:"mail adress", 
  phone:"654654321"
}
```

any ideas how i do that?

Comment: If `userData` is a regular javascript object, you can use `userData.email`. More on how objects work in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

If userData is regular JavaScript object, then you can use userData.email. Otherwise if it is a string, then you can convert your string into JSON and access email property of it.

```
var userData = '{"name":"name surname", "email":"mail adress", "phone":"654654321"}';
var json = JSON.parse(userData);
console.log(json.email);
```

Comment: What OP is showing is not valid JSON if it is indeed a string

Comment: Please check your string if it valid for JSON before parsing it to JSON